# RPM install showing "Installation of an identical package is not allowed"

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm

Hi I'm facing a weird issue while installing an RPM package on redhat linux:

```
    # rpm -ivh OMNI-UTIL-K269.02SP6.OMNIUTIL.ECN9S60-6.x86_64.rpm
    Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    INSTALL ERROR: Installation of an identical package is not allowed
    error: %pre(OMNI-UTIL-K269.02SP6.OMNIUTIL.ECN9S60-6.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
    error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping OMNI-UTIL-K269.02SP6.OMNIUTIL.ECN9S60-6
```

Though this successfully installs if I use the `--noscripts` option , but i want a clean install.

I've checked that this rpm is not installed on the system:

```
    # rpm -qa | grep -i omni | wc -l
    0
```

Have anyone faced this issue before while installing any RPMs? This is a first for me.

Comment: Hi! Try `rpm -qp --scripts` and check why there is the error in script.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue:

```
    # find / -name OMNI-UTIL-K269.02SP6.OMNIUTIL.ECN9S60-6.x86_64.rpm
    /root/auto_install/airwide/signalware/OMNI-UTIL-K269.02SP6.OMNIUTIL.ECN9S60-6.x86_64.rpm
    /apps/auto_install/airwide/signalware/OMNI-UTIL-K269.02SP6.OMNIUTIL.ECN9S60-6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: I deleted the RPM path from /root/auto_install directory and then it's installing without issues.